# How to exclude a special case from a directive behavior?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive

I am trying to fix a bug that I'm getting while searching on my page. I have a component to search in all of my settings, like this:

[image: Search settings component]

Everything is working fine, the search is returning the values it is supposed to, but when I remove the search criteria, I note that the first letter of the criteria is still showing and does not disappear, even when the search settings field is empty, just like this:

[image: Avatar string with A selected]

After two hours of checking at the code, I can see where in the code is the problem, but I don't know how to fix it.

This is my component's html:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="standard">
      <input matInput
             pageSearch
             placeholder="{{'searchSettings'|translate}}">
    </mat-form-field>
```

As you can see, I am using a directive called `pageSearch` that is defined as follows and contains a method `valueChange` that executes each time a keyboard key is released:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    const subscription = this.router.events
      .pipe(filter(e => e instanceof NavigationStart))
      .subscribe(event => {
          if (event) {
            this.pageSearchService.term.next('');
          }
        }
      );
    this.subscriptionsManager.add(subscription);
  }

@HostListener('keyup')
  valueChange() {
    this.pageSearchService.term.next(
      this.elementRef.nativeElement.value
    );
  }
```

This directive uses the `pageSearchService`, defined as follows:

```
@Injectable()
export class PageSearchService {
  /**
   * Current search term.
   */
  term: BehaviorSubject<string>;
  /**
   * Event to emit when visibility should change in the searchable.
   */
  searchableMatch: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  constructor() {
    this.term = new BehaviorSubject('');
  }
}
```

I have a slight idea that the problem might be that it is always expecting a `next()` value, and when it is null, it just does not run, but the last value it had is still frozen in there.

I have tried changing the method `valueChange` in the directive, but every time I end up closing the subscription to the BehaviorSubject. These are the things I have tried:

1. Add a condition to check if the string is empty and not to call the `BehaviorSubject`

```
valueChange() {
    if (this.elementRef.nativeElement.value !== '') {
      this.pageSearchService.term.next(
        this.elementRef.nativeElement.value
      );
    }
  }
```

It did not work, I also tried to unsubscribe and subscribe again, but it did not worked either

```
valueChange() {
    if (this.elementRef.nativeElement.value !== '') {
      this.pageSearchService.term.next(
        this.elementRef.nativeElement.value
      );
    } else {
      this.pageSearchService.term.unsubscribe();
      this.pageSearchService.term._subscribe(this.elementRef.nativeElement.value);
    }
  }
```

It is giving me this error:

[image: Error when unsubscribing]

So now I do not know what else to do. How can I ask the directive not to behave a certain way given the string `''`?

The `searchableMatch` EventEmitter is used by other 3 directives, as follows:

The SearchNoResultsDirective:

```
export class SearchNoResultsDirective implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input('searchNoResults') sectionsId: string[];
  subscriptionsManager: Subscription = new Subscription();
  visibility: {
    term: string,
    visible: boolean
  } = {
    term: '',
    visible: true
  };

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef,
              private renderer: Renderer2,
              private pageSearchService: PageSearchService) {
  }

.
.
.

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const subscription = this.pageSearchService.searchableMatch.subscribe(match => {
      if (this.sectionsId.indexOf(match.sectionId) >= 0 ) {
        this.update({
          term: match.term,
          visible: match.visible
        });
      }
    });
    this.subscriptionsManager.add(subscription);
  }
}
```

The SearchableSectionDirective:

```
export class SearchableSectionDirective extends BaseClass implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input('searchableSection') sectionId: string;

.
.
.

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const subscription = this.pageSearchService.searchableMatch.subscribe(match => {
      if (match.sectionId === this.sectionId) {
        this.update({
          term: match.term,
          visible: match.visible
        });
      }
    });
    this.subscriptionsManager.add(subscription);
  }
}
```

And the SearchableDirective:

```
export class SearchableDirective implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input('searchable') sectionId: string;
  @Input() highlightColor = '#FFF176';
  match: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  subscriptionsManager: Subscription = new Subscription();
  originalText: string;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.originalText = this.elementRef.nativeElement.innerText;
    this.subscriptionsManager.add(
      this.pageSearchService.term.subscribe(term => this.checkIfMatch(term))
    );
  }

  checkIfMatch(val: string) {
    let match = false;
    let clean = false;
    if (val) {
      const startInd = this.originalText.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.trim().toLowerCase());
      if (startInd > -1) {
        match = true;
        const startText = this.render.createText(this.originalText.slice(0, startInd));
        const matchText = this.render.createText(this.originalText.slice(startInd, startInd + val.trim().length));
        const endText = this.render.createText(this.originalText.slice(startInd + val.trim().length, this.originalText.length));

        const matchSpan = this.render.createElement('span');
        this.render.appendChild(
          matchSpan,
          matchText
        );
        this.render.setStyle(
          matchSpan,
          'background',
          this.highlightColor
        );

        this.elementRef.nativeElement.innerHTML = '';

        this.render.appendChild(
          this.elementRef.nativeElement,
          startText
        );
        this.render.appendChild(
          this.elementRef.nativeElement,
          matchSpan
        );
        this.render.appendChild(
          this.elementRef.nativeElement,
          endText
        );
      } else {
        clean = true;
      }
    } else if (this.originalText) {
      clean = true;
    }

    **if (clean) {
      // this is how the solution looks
      this.elementRef.nativeElement.innerHTML = this.originalText;
    }**

    if (this.sectionId) {
      this.pageSearchService.searchableMatch.emit({
        sectionId: this.sectionId,
        term: val,
        visible: match
      });

      this.match.emit({
        term: val,
        visible: match
      });
    }
  }
}
```

I am looking through these 3 directives to see if I find the problem.

Comment: try listening event `document:keypress` instead of `keyup`

Comment: @NimittShah I already tried that, it did not work, in fact it broke the search logic, now it has a delay when I type

Comment: it would be helpful if you create https://stackblitz.com/ app.

Comment: @NimittShah I currently work at a private project. I'm afraid I cannot disclose more than I already have, since my PO would not approve it. Sorry :(

Comment: Does `searchableMatch` control the highlighting of the 'A' in 'Avatar'? When does `searchableMatch` emit values?

Comment: @AlexK The `searchableMatch` eventEmitter is used by other 3 directives, I will modify the question to show you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only problem is the function where you have putted the logic. 
I think you need to only add in `checkIfMatch`

```
checkIfMatch(val: string) {

    let match = false;
    let clean = false;
    if (val) {

       //func logic

     } else {
        // you need to add else block to the function
        this.elementRef.nativeElement.innerHTML = this.originalText;

     }

}
```

Comment: I tried that right now, it did not work, the last letter is still highlighted. I believe I whould reset the render object that has the style, I'm searching how to do that. Thanks a lot anyway

Comment: @DairelysGarcíaRivas please make sure you have not any conditions on the  `valueChange()`

Comment: the ` valueChange()` should do only `this.pageSearchService.term.next( this.elementRef.nativeElement.value);`

Comment: This directive has no `valueChange()` method

Comment: I mean the pageSearch directive

Comment: the final fix was on the `if (clean)` condition at the end of the `checkIfMatch` method in the `SearchableDirective`.

Comment: Hello @DairelysGarcíaRivas, glad to know, and how you fixed it?

Comment: Check in the description of the task, in the `SearchableDirective`, I updated it and placed a comment for you to see how it is now.

Comment: @DairelysGarcíaRivas one more question. Are You removed the `else if(this.originalText) {}` before add `else {
        // you need to add else block to the function
        this.elementRef.nativeElement.innerHTML = this.originalText;

     }` ?

Comment: Nope, note that I did not include it in that line, but in the condition that verifies if `clean` is true

Comment: @DairelysGarcíaRivas your condition `else if(this.originalText)` always returns true

Comment: @DairelysGarcíaRivas that's why my example didn't work for you, but I found the case where my example will not work correctly, when  `startInd === -1` You will have the same problem with my example.

Comment: I tried using that value, it is still working for me, as it is in the code posted in the description